Using Sagemath, how to exactly find out what the order of a point of an elliptic curve in the twisted Edwards form is?
Simple question and I’m fully aware of the other question, but I need the answer for curves in the twisted Edwards form and I suppose converting the curve and the point to the Weierstrass form would change the resulting order being computed (unless I’m wrong)…

Third question : the order of a point is the same as the curve’s order ?

https://neuromancer.sk/std/other/Ed25519

@kelalaka I’m afraid 1 of the curve I have in mind isn’t on the neuromancer database and thus had it’s order to be computed because it’s also undocumented.

Each curve may need a different Edward to Weistrass birational transformation. So how we can know what you have in your mind?

@kelalaka I’m thinking about the Babyjujub curve.

https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2494

@kelalaka and I’m not thinking about the base or generator points.

Taking the standard birational transformation from Edwards to Montgomery form does not change the order (the map is a group isomorphism where defined). Moreover, in any group, the order of a point must be a divisor of the order of the curve, so there are only few choices for a point's order on the curve you are considering.

@yyyyyyy anyway, sagemath only do weirestrass.

The order of an element $P$ of a finite group is, by definition, the smallest strictly positive integer $k$ with $k\cdot P=\underbrace{P+P+\cdots+P}_{k\text{ terms}}$ equal to the group neutral. This order divides the group order (it's number of elements). To identify the order of a given finite group element, a general technique is thus to try all $k$ dividing the group order by increasing value, stopping at the first $k$ with $k\cdot P$ the group neutral. One optimization (not even indispensable here) adds caching of earlier computed $P_k=k\cdot P$, and for $k'$ multiple of $k$ compute $P_{k'}=(k'/k)\cdot P_k$. Further refinements can save on the cache size by exploring a tree according to the prime factorization of the group order.

The rest of this answer is restricted to twisted Edwards curves commonly used in cryptography
$$E=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb F_p\times\mathbb F_p\ \text{ such that }-x^2+y^2=1+d\,x^2y^2\,\}$$
with givens: prime $p$ with $p\bmod 4=1$, integer $d$ with the Legendre symbol $\left(\frac d p\right)=-1$, order (number of elements) $|E|=h\,n$ with $h=4$ or $h=8$ and odd prime $n$. Artificially small examples are $(p,d,h,n)=(53,2,4,11)$ or $(73,5,8,11)$. The group law is:
$$\bigl(x_1,y_1\bigr)+\bigl(x_2,y_2\bigr)=\bigl((x_1y_2+x_2y_1)/(1+d\,x_1x_2y_1y_2),(x_1x_2+y_1y_2)/(1-d\,x_1x_2y_1y_2)\bigr)$$
The order of an element $P$ of the curve is a divisor of the curve's order $|E|=h\,n$. It thus can only be one of $\{1,2,4,n,2n,4n\}$ if $h=4$, $\{1,2,4,8,n,2n,4n,8n\}$ if $h=8$. There are:

$1$ element of order $1$ : the neutral/point at infinity $(0,1)$
$1$ element of order $2$ : $(0,-1)$
$2$ elements of order $4$, of the form $(\pm j,0)$ where $j^2=-1$. $j$ can be found by Tonelli–Shanks.
$n-1$ elements of order $n$
$n-1$ elements of order $2n$
$2n-2$ elements of order $4n$
and additionally if $h=8$

$4$ elements of order $8$, which differ by the sign of $x$ and/or $y\,$; in the example $(p,d,h,n)=(73,5,8,11)$ these points are $(\pm25,\pm18)$
$4n-4$ elements of order $8n$



Here, from a curve element $P$ given as $(x,y)$, we can use this algorithm:

if $x=0$

if $y=1$, the order of $P$ is $1$, done.
if $y=-1$, the order of $P$ is $2$, done.
the point $P$ is not on the curve, done.


if $y=0$

if $x^2=-1$, the order of $P$ is $4$, done.
the point $P$ is not on the curve, done.


if $h=8$

compute $P_2=P+P=(x_2,y_2)$
if $y_2=0$

if ${x_2}^2=-1$, the order of $P$ is $8$, done.
the point $P$ is not on the curve, done.




compute $P_n=n\cdot P=(x_n,y_n)$, which is the most compute intensive part

if $x_n=0$

if $y_n=1$, the order of $P$ is $n$, done.
if $y_n=-1$, the order of $P$ is $2n$, done.
the point $P$ is not on the curve, done.


if $y_n=0$

if ${x_n}^2=-1$, the order of $P$ is $4n$, done.


if $h=8$

compute $P_{2n}=P_n+P_n=(x_{2n},y_{2n})$
if $y_{2n}=0$ and ${x_{2n}}^2=-1$, the order of $P$ is $8n$, done.




the point $P$ is not on the curve, done.

Note: for the two $h=8$ cases, we could alternatively precompute the coordinates of points of order $8$ and match $P$ and $P_n$ against these, rather than compute $P_2$ and $P_{2n}$.

Thinking about how to do this in SageMath: A problem is SageMath's EllipticCurve has no direct support for Edwards curves, twisted or not; only Weierstrass curves.
However there's an isomorphism to convert one into the other. That's discussed in MPHELL and in Dan NGuyen's Correspondence between elliptic curves in Edwards-Bernstein and Weierstrass forms. This would allow to use the build-in order for the element mapped from the twisted Edwards curve.
Another way is to just code the above algorithm; but we need to re-code at least the group law and, for best efficiency of the $n\cdot P$ part, point multiplication in a coordinate system minimizing modular inversions, e.g. projective coordinates where $(x,y)$ is represented by $(X,Y,Z)$ with $x\,Z=X$ and $y\,Z=Y$, see this page of the Explicit Formula Database.
